# Im trying scramble randomaly strings but some of the strings dosen't get scrambled at all what could it be?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
private static StringBuilder MakeRandomwords(string theWord)
{
    var jumbleSb = new StringBuilder();
    jumbleSb.Append(theWord);
    int lengthSb = jumbleSb.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthSb; ++i)
    {
        int index1 = (RandomGen.Next() % lengthSb);
        int index2 = (RandomGen.Next() % lengthSb);

        Char temp = jumbleSb[index1];
        jumbleSb[index1] = jumbleSb[index2];
        jumbleSb[index2] = temp;
    }
    return jumbleSb;
}
```

And this is the List that im using to build the scrambled words:

```
private void GetText()
{
    _lengthaboveone = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < _words.Count; i++)
    {
        string word = _words[i];
        if (word.Length < 4) continue;

        string first = word.Substring(0, 1);
        string last = word.Substring(word.Length - 1, 1);
        string middle = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2);
        _lengthaboveone.Add(middle);
        _words[i] = first + MakeRandomwords(middle) + last;
    }
    _scrambledWords = _words;
}
```

In the end the List _scrambledWords contain over 1000 strings in each index a string of a word most of them scrambled but some of them are left the same as they were in the original.

The question is if there is something wrong with my MakeRandomwords ?
Could be it did scrambled the word and it was scrambled to how it was before ? So maybe i need to add something to the code that will keep scramble the word untill the word is scrambled by compraing it ot the original untill the word is scrambled ?

Comment: Where is `RandomGen` declared and initialized?

Comment: RandomGen is declared and init in the top of the Form1 before the constructor : private static readonly Random RandomGen = new Random();

Comment: Of course the strings that are not scrambled have more than 4 characters right?

Comment: Consider calling it on a word only two characters long. Each time you generate `index1` and `index2`, they'll either be equal or opposite. If they're equal, no swap occurs. If they're opposite, then the letters are swapped. If, overall, an **even** number of swaps occur, you'll get the same word back as you put in, *no matter how many iterations you run*. For longer words, there will be similar sequences of swaps that eventually put all of the letters back where they started.

Comment: Steve yes all the words are 4 chars or above those are not scrambled are 4 chars long some of them 5 chars long.

Comment: Damien can you show me how to do it an example ?

Comment: If you randomly scramble a 4 letter word, it will have a 1 in 24 chance of being the same as the original. For a 5 letter word, the chance is 1 in 120 of being the same. So even with a perfect scrambler, you will still get unchanged strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Fisher–Yates shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and implement the following pseudo code to achieve a good distribution of elements:

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
    for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
        j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
        exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

---

To elaborate on Tim Schmelter's comment asking about `RandomGen.Next()`, in case you've been wondering: If you instantiate a new `Random` instance every time you're entering the `for` loop, the generated pseudo-random numbers will by nature be quite repetitive. This is due to the way that the `Random` class is implemented in the .NET framework. By reusing a shared instance like you do, one can avoid that issue.

This is not the problem here, though. In your algorithm, you're picking two random array elements and swapping them. It's highly likely that there are some array elements that never get selected this way. Thus, there's a good chance that some elements won't have changed their position in the array when you're done, which is why it doesn't look shuffled well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of randomly swapping two locations, swap every location to a random location... it will look more random because each element will have moved.  With your current design there is a good chance some items won't ever move.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lengthSb; ++i)
{
    int index1 = i;
    int index2 = (RandomGen.Next() % lengthSb);

    Char temp = jumbleSb[index1];
    jumbleSb[index1] = jumbleSb[index2];
    jumbleSb[index2] = temp;
}
```